# gdrive command line oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-drive-api

Suddenly, `gdrive` command line tool stops working, and always gives the following error message:

```sh
Failed to get about: Get https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?alt=json&fields=maxImportSizes%2CmaxUploadSize%2CstorageQuota%2Cuser: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Managed to resolve this by retriggering `gcloud` authorization with:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because your authorization token has expired.

Currently there is an open Issue to improve this error message [here](https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive/issues/442).

You should delete your token with `rm ~/.gdrive/token_v*.json`
then run the `gdrive about` command to reauthorize

Answer (score 2):

The steps I fixed it:

1. `rm ~/.gdrive/token_v2.json` as other answer suggested.
2. But I get danger error if I open the link get from `gdrive about` to re-authorize: [image]
3. So I create a drive project by go to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js and click "**Enable the Drive API**":

   [image]
4. Click the "**API Console**" link on that dialog:

   [image]
5. To make default redirect url (i.e. `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`) works, we need [**Installed type app**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) and can't use "**Web application type app**"(which only allow http/https scheme). So click "**Create credentials**" and choose "**Oauth client ID**" item:

   [image]
6. Ensure select "**Other**" type:

   [image]
7. Copy "**Client ID**" and "**Client secret**" from created item. `cd` to `~/.go/src/github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/`, then replace both at this two variables in `handlers_drive.go` file, save it, e.g.:

   ```go
       const ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
       const ClientSecret = "xxx"
   ```
8. Then run `go install` at that directory. Now run `gdrive about` and open that link in web browser. I get `This app isn't verified` error page. You are the author who created that app on above steps and suppose safe. Nevertheless simply click "**Advanced**" link and click `Go to Quickstart (unsafe)` link: [image]
9. Click "**Allow**" it, copy/paste the code back to `gdrive about` and done:

[image]

Comment: As of today there is no option to select 'Application type' - Other.|
I was not able to do this. It always asks me 
"Enter verification code:"